# Get a list of SQLite hidden columns

Tags: sqlite

I'm defining my own table-valued-functions in sqlite. I'd like to be able to get a list of these functions, along with the names of their arguments and return columns.

I can get everything except a list of their arguments.

Arguments of table-valued-functions are basically hidden columns in SQLite. This is convenient because they don't show up the results, but my problem is I can't inspect them using `pragma table_info`.

Is there any way to get a list of hidden columns for a (virtual) table?

Comment: They show up in the schema, but that is not easily parseable.

Comment: @CL. Hm, how do I get the schema? Is it a string?

Comment: `.schema` in the `sqlite3` command-line shell, or read the [sqlite_master table](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master).

Answer (score 1):

```
PRAGMA table_xinfo("table_name")

table_xinfo = table_info + hidden columns
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! It will be helpful if you explain your answers with the code. Also, format your answers for code accordingly using the editor.